# Deploying Angular 2 using Team City

Tags: angular

Is there any way to add the deployment of Angular 2 applications to a current backend deployment using Team City? Currently I've got a complex .NET Web Api backend solution that is already part of the Continious Integration process and the UI Angular 2 project is part of that solution. I'm still struggling on how to unify the backend deployemnt with the front-end with Team City. Is there any guidelines or instructions for doing that ?

Comment: Can you check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48660214/1051784?
It uses **Team City 2017** which wasn't available when you ask this question.